# "[NetworkError]" in Angular SSR console with no additional information

Tags: angular, docker, server-side-rendering

**The problem:** [NetworkError] in Angular SSR console with no additional information.

[image of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBJpU.jpg)

**Note:** *it does not seem to break the code*

**Environment information:** Angular 8.1 SSR is served with NGINX, running in docker container. Http calls are made to the other docker container. 13 of which are XHR calls.

I have not found any information about the problem like this, and I have not troubleshoot it thoroughly myself either yet. I'll answer it if I'll finally troubleshoot it, though maybe someone done that already?

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 4):

Here are the tips that might help locate you the source of the problem.

### 1. Debug

In your app folder run: `ng run <your_project_name>:serve-ssr`. It gives you benefits:

- Renders the Universal app and triggers the NetworkError.
- Auto-refreshes on file change, renders reasonable fast - this will allow you to go step-by-step fast and pinpoint the problem.

Compare this to `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` which will take much longer to render the changes.

### 2. Absolute URLs

Follow [Angular Server-Side rendering tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/universal#using-absolute-urls-for-server-requests) and make sure you have set absolute URLs.

Comment: The URLs are indeed absolute, however, I will try to look into it as you have described in 1st point

Comment: Omg, you just saved my day! Indeed I had an url that looked like "//urlhere", without the protocol. Once updated and added the protocol, error was gone. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this while working on a new centralized dev environment for my team. I was already using absolute URL's, and in my current configuration, using a domain name would not work due to DNS/load balancer not being pointed to the new server.

I have an angular application running on a node container and a PHP container serving my backend. Tying all of this together, I have an nginx container (with no exposed ports) hooked up to traefik - where basically everything requesting `/api` is routed to my PHP container. All SSR requests need to be set to my proxy, while client side requests to the API need to use the absolute url.

I was able to solve this by creating an HTTP interceptor to rewrite requests to communicate to my nginx container (named `proxy`) in the docker compose project.

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerDockerInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const apiReq = req.clone({ url: `http://proxy${req.url}` });
        return next.handle(apiReq);
    }
}
```

This interceptor was added to my AppServerModule.